# Signedness of char and Unicode in C++0x

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, char, c++11

From the C++0x working draft, the new char types (**char16_t** and **char32_t**) for handling Unicode will be unsigned (**uint_least16_t** and **uint_least32_t** will be the underlying types).

But as far as I can see (not very far perhaps) a type **char8_t** (based on **uint_least8_t**) is not defined. Why ?

And it's even more confusing when you see that a new **u8** encoding prefix is introduced for UTF-8 string literal... based on old friend (sign/unsigned) **char**. Why ?

**Update** : 
There's a proposal to add a new type : char8_t

char8_t: A type for UTF-8 characters and strings (Revision 1)
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r1.html

Answer (score 4):

char will be the type used for UTF-8 because it's redefined to be sure it can be used with it:

> For the purpose of enhancing support
>   for Unicode in C++ compilers, **the
>   definition of the type char has been
>   modified to be both at least the size
>   necessary to store an eight-bit coding
>   of UTF-8 and large enough to contain
>   any member of the compiler's basic
>   execution character set**. It was
>   previously defined as only the latter.
>   There are three Unicode encodings that
>   C++0x will support: UTF-8, UTF-16, and
>   UTF-32. In addition to the previously
>   noted changes to the definition of
>   char, C++0x will add two new character
>   types: char16_t and char32_t. These
>   are designed to store UTF-16 and
>   UTF-32 respectively.

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x

Most of UTF-8 application uses char already anyway on PC/mac.

Comment: Doesn't say a word of signedness.

Comment: Why the awkward phrasing of the bold part?  Isn't "eight-bit coding of UTF-8" redundant?

Comment: Well that's wikipedia, the wording changes often and can greatly variate in quality. However I didn't found another source that summarize those unicode related features.

Answer (score 1):

`char16_t` and `char32_t` are supposed to be usable for representing code points. Since there are no negative code points, it's sensible for these to be unsigned.

UTF-8 does not represent code points directly, so it doesn't matter whether `u8`'s underlying type is signed or not.

Comment: If I want to store the character é (U+00E9), that is the two byte sequence 0xC3 0xA9, with an array of signed char it will fail :signed char e_acute = {0xC3,0xA9} => this will truncate the value.
So if your system define char as signed char, it's still a problem. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Very seldom do you need to enter the bytes manually: often, like you say, the `u8` is used. So, high bytes just get treated as negative numbers in that case.

Comment: Chris, is there a guarantee that the pair of conversions `unsigned char -> signed char -> unsigned char` will yield the original value? The former conversion is implementation-defined and I couldn't find any clause that would guarantee the roundtrip.

Comment: @avakar: I'm not sure why the roundtripping is important in this case (unless I misread your comment). The way I understand the task is this: you need a way to convert a bunch of `char` into a bunch of `char16_t` or `char32_t`. You could easily widen a `char` during this conversion.

Comment: My point is that if you're receiving UTF-8 data from somewhere (as a sequence of numbers in range 0--255, which is how UTF-8 is defined), you can't reliably store them in a char array because the value you'd obtain by casting back to `unsigned char` could be different (and I'm not even sure if `CHAR_BIT` is guaranteed to be at least 8). For reliability, you have to use `uint_least8_t`, and to me it seems useful and consistent to provide `char8_t` typedef for it.

Comment: Nah, you never interpret UTF8 directly.  You pass it to a runtime support function that converts it to a native character type, like wchar_t.  So it doesn't matter what kind of bag of bytes you put it in.

Comment: Reading an UTF-8 file into a signed char buffer will produce the same problem. 
Also if your char is signed, you can't assume that a std::string (basic_string<char>) is a valid UTF-8 string. I don't see how this is changing even with u8 ?

Comment: @avakar: Normally, you read in byte data from a file or a network. Those will usually be stored as `char` already, in whatever signedness is native to the system. So in a signed case (in the OP's example), 0xC3, 0xA9 is read in as -0x3D, -0x57 (on two's complement systems). That's fine: the conversion functions can still meaningfully promote that into an int, and process them into actual code points that way.

Comment: `char`'s guaranteed range might be at small as [-127..+127] if signed and if the implementation uses a signed-magnitude representation instead of two's-complement.  In fact, the valid range of `char` may be as small as [0..127] if your host character set is merely ASCII, even though I think it still must be at least 8 bits.  Reading "raw bytes" into an array of `char` therefore seems theoretically non-portable.  I've always used arrays of `unsigned char` when I needed a bag of bytes.  Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Never mind.  I read that C++0x has _changed the definition_ of `char` in such a way as to rule out the representations which lead to the [0..127] and [-127..+127] ranges. So once you're on a new, compliant compiler, an array of `char` is sufficient to hold a bag of bytes.  Until then, though, `unsigned char` is a safer bet.

Answer (score 1):

The C++0x draft doesn't seem to indicate whether or not the new Unicode character types are signed or unsigned.  However, as others have already mentioned, since there are no negative Unicode codepoints it would make more sense for `char16_t` and `char32_t` to be unsigned.  (Then again, it would have made sense for `char` to be unsigned, yet we've been dealing with "negative" characters since the 70s.)

Also, since UTF-16 ranges from 0x0 through 0xFFFF (ignoring surrogate pairs), you'd need the entire range of an unsigned 16-bit integer to properly represent all values.  It would be awkward, to say the least, if codepoints 0x8000 through 0xFFFF were represented as negative numbers with a `char16_t`.

Anyway, until the C++0x committee says something definitive on the matter, you can always just check your implementation:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_signed<char16_t>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This prints out `false` using GCC 4.45 on Linux.  So on one platform, at least, the new Unicode types are definitely unsigned.